# Url's in react-native android index.android.bundle file

Tags: android, react-native, apk

After generated the apk file using android studio, I unzip and check the index.android.bundle file, i can see lot of url's exist in the file. Can anyone please help me why these url's are exist and how can we avoid in release build.

Example:

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/#flex-align
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineShiftProperty
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo
https://xcarpentier.github.io/react-native-country-picker-modal/countries/
https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/useMove.html
https://mrousavy.github.io/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/troubleshooting
```

[image]